# Using electron, how do handle incoming calls from twilio when the render process is dead

Tags: electron, twilio

I am using the Twilio Voice SDK to make voice calls from the client. For the scenario of incoming calls, we want to be able to pop open a new window to handle the call.

To do the above, i am trying the following flow.

1. Initialize the twilio device client in the main process
2. listen for incoming calls
3. When we get an incoming call, we pass the connection instance via ipc to the newly created render process
4. The render process initializes its own client and accepts the call

This doesn't work, is there any better way to achieve this? I would ideally like to listen for the call in the main (node) process and handle it (accept call, getusermedia, etc) in the render process

TIA

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.